# Using CanCan how to authorize a user to edit sub models of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a model structure like this.

```
User
 |
 +-- Order
      |
      +-- OrderItem
           |
           +-- OrderItemNote
```

Order holds a direct relation with User, so I can do `:user_id => user.id` in the `Ability` class for `User.role? :customer` (for example) to let them edit their own orders.

However, short of adding `:user_id` columns to `OrderItem` and `OrderItemNote` I have no idea how to configure CanCan to allow the user to edit their own `OrderItem` and `OrderItemNote` objects.

Can anyone help out?

## Update:

I went with jvnill's answer, because I'm using RailsAdmin (and it's simpler to do an Ability class, rather than a `load_resource`. In normal circumstances, CanCan's `load_resource` is a better way to go.

Note: while the first level of nesting is handled by:

```
can :manage, OrderItem, order: { user_id: user.id }
```

The deeper level nesting...:

```
can :manage, OrderItemNote, order_item: { order: { user_id: user.id } }
```

... threw a SQL error

```
no such column: order_items.orders
```

and it appears that CanCan treats deeper level references (ie. `order` in this case) as database field references, not through the model (I tried a few tricks with virtual attributes etc. to provide an `order_id` or even the `user_id` but anything other than a real database field name is not recognised.) - I'm on limited time to investigate this further, I'm leaving these notes, for myself, so I can look into it later.

In the end I decided the deeper level nesting was unnecessary, and included the note in the order item itself, so the model is like so:

```
User
 |
 +-- Order
      |
      +-- OrderItem (which includes a note)
```

Comment: do you laod oder_item_notes through the whole chain?

Comment: @apneadiving - What do you mean? - User has a reference to Order (belongs_to :user), OrderItem (belongs_to :order) and OrderItemNote (belongs_to :order_item)

Comment: depending on your needs, it could make sense to load all intermediate objects, and cancan as builtin methods to do it. Proceeding this way, you could authorize at the order level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest way to do this is like this

```
can :manage, OrderItem, order: { user_id: user.id }
can :manage, OrderItemNote, order_item: { order: { user_id: user.id } }
```

Comment: I prefer the `load_and_authorize through:` alternative, but good answer anyway, +1

Comment: ah cool. now i get what you were asking in your comments. you learn something new everyday.

Comment: actually, since I use this, I've divided my `abilities.rb` file by 3 (but it's sometimes undesirable to load all objects...)

Comment: @apneadiving - It would be cool if you'd post an answer showing how you do it.

Comment: @Slomojo: if you request it, ok

Comment: Sorry, had to un-mark this, the `OrderItem` ability works fine, but the `OrderItemNote` ability throws a SQL error, `no such column: order_items.orders` ... Hope you have an idea how to fix it!

Comment: how is your association between order_item_note and order_item defined?

Comment: I decided that the deep nesting is a bad smell and reorganised the model so that `order_item` includes the `note` (ie. have multiple order items with one note, rather than one order item and many notes.) - However, the models were associated ok, e.g. I could do nested actions via my controllers, so I'm not sure what's going on with CanCan in this instance, I'll re-visit it when I'm not on a crunch ;)

Answer (score 2):

If loading all intermediate objects makes sense and if you have adapted routes (ie with all necessary ids):

```
class OrderItemNotesController
  load_resource :order,           through: :current_user
  load_resource :order_item,      through: :order
  load_resource :order_item_note, through: :order_item
```

This way, you don't need any ability: all objects are retrieved through associations.

Should really be adapted to situations of course (and don't forget you can still do: `load_and_authorize_resource` if needed)

Comment: That's pretty cool, for my use case, I have Rails_Admin to contend with as well, so adding the `can` directives in `Ability` is necessary. (well, `AdminAbility` in my case.)